# Macro needed to match next best number

Tags: vba, excel

please excuse my ignorance on all of this as it is very new to me and outside of my immediate area. So do bear with me!

I am looking for some help on a spreadsheet I am working on to calculate numerous metrics for jump height based on force data.

I have used Index and Match functions for the first part (to find bodyweight), however I believe i will now need a VBA syntax to help find the position of B. Here's the caveat, theoretically B should be the same as A (as it is bodyweight), but in most cases it wont be due to fluctuation in the data collection (measured at 1000hz).

I effectively need to ask excel to do the following,

" Find point B which is = to A, if it is not = to A find the next highest number which is as close as possible"

Alternatively i could ask it

" Find point B which is closest to A from range (b3239:b9999999)" as this is one cell after point A.

Does anyone know how this can be done? Ideally I would like to make this as automated as possible as when i enter new data in i don't want to have to change anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Happy to send images or the sheet if need be.

Thanks in advance everyone!

I have tried:

`[=INDEX(B2:B999999,MATCH(MIN(ABS(B2:B999999-L13)),ABS(B2:B99‌​9999-L13),0))]` but this comes up with a #NA Error.

I have also tried a couple based of some research.
`Range("B2:B999999").Find(ActiveCell("13", "12"),ActiveCell("11","12"),,XlWhole=ActiveCell("13", "12"),,,True)`

Comment: We will not write code for you. Please show us what you've written so far.

Comment: Sure that's understandable. I have tried the following from looking around 

[=INDEX(B2:B999999,MATCH(MIN(ABS(B2:B999999-L13)),ABS(B2:B999999-L13),0))] 

this comes up with a #NA Error. 

Ive never written code before but have tried a couple based of some research and have used ;

Range("B2:B999999").Find(ActiveCell("13", "12"),ActiveCell("11","12"),,XlWhole=ActiveCell("13", "12"),,,True)

ofcourse this didnt go down too well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try vlookup. Vlookup has a function with closest match.

https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/vlookup-closest-match-true/